# How to use Status in own code in Play

Tags: scala, playframework

Playversion is 2.6.12.

I want to use Results.Status in my own code like

```
   // in my code somewhere
   def doSomething(status:Results.Status) { ....} 

   // in controller
   doSomething(Ok)   <---- results in error
```

But I the Ok inside a controller seems not to be of type Results.Status

```
[error] found : MyController.this.Status
[error] required: play.api.mvc.Results.Status
```

Any ideas how to use Status in my own code outside controllers?

The helper code is

```
import org.scalactic.{Bad, Good, Or}
import play.api.libs.json.Json
import play.api.mvc.Result
import play.api.mvc.Results.Status

object Helper {

  def toResult[T](r:Or[T, Result], s:Status):Result = {
    r match {
      case Good(entity) => s(Json.toJson(entity))
      case Bad(badRequest) => badRequest
    }
  }
}
```

The controller code definition is extending

```
class AuthBaseController @Inject()(acc: AuthControllerComponents) extends BaseController with AuthRequestMarkerContext {
```

where BaseController leads to

```
trait ControllerHelpers extends Results with HttpProtocol with Status with HeaderNames with ContentTypes with RequestExtractors with Rendering with RequestImplicits
```

extending Status.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always explicitly pass the requested type:

```
doSomething(play.api.mvc.Results.Ok)
```

I suppose if you just import `play.api.mvc.Results._` in your controller, you will have an import conflict (you can still try it), but just importing `play.api.mvc.Results`, and then using it like this

```
doSomething(Results.Ok)
```

should work.

Comment: Yes, play.api.mvc.Results.Ok works (checked), but looks ugly ;-) See edit on my original post.

Comment: Thanks, see my edit, I probably have to use my own BaseController because the Play BaseController extends for whatever reason Status.

Answer (score 0):

```
[error] found : MyController.this.Status
[error] required: play.api.mvc.Results.Status
```

Status is a specific type that depends on the controller. To have a function that's a certain type, that doesn't care about the parent type you can use the # symbol like this:

```
def doSomething(status:Results#Status) { ....}
```